# Should we move questions that ask about the features of the Stack Exchange sites to Meta?

Tags: support, questions, scope

Consider these questions:

- [observer(subscriber) Design Pattern on Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8138627)
- [How can I make something like the Stack Overflow tag popover?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5325134)
- [Stack Overflow tags - How do they display info on mouse over?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5513274)

They discuss the technical aspects of Stack Exchange sites. Should we move them here? What should be done with new questions that are similar to these, were such to appear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are, fundamentally, web programming questions. As such, they are on topic for Stack Overflow and should not be migrated anywhere.

The fact that the asker wants to do something the same way as Stack Overflow does not mean that the question is about Stack Overflow. That's just the motivating context.

Question [number 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138627/observersubscriber-design-pattern-on-web) is actually about using the observer-subscriber pattern to implement asynchronous updates in a web browser.

Questions [number 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325134/how-can-i-make-something-like-the-stack-overflow-tag-popover) and [number 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513274/stack-overflow-tags-how-do-they-display-info-on-mouse-over) are about displaying pop-ups on mouse-hover over elements displayed in a web browser.

Questions on Meta need to have one of the following tags:

- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), which should be self-explanatory: you're reporting a bug or unexpected behavior that you've encountered while using a Stack Exchange site.
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), for bug reports wearing a fancy suit.
- [support](/questions/tagged/support), where you need assistance with using one of the site's features or have encountered a problem when using the site.
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), the fallback for everything else.

While you *could* use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) to ask on Meta how Stack Exchange implemented some feature, you're almost certainly going to get a better answer from a knowledgeable web programmer on Stack Overflow. This is especially true for front-end stuff, where it isn't even necessary to work at Stack Overflow to see how they built a feature.

Comment: Worth mentioning we have the [architecture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) tag over on the uber Meta.